# Insert procedure with 2 string parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2012

I wrote this procedure to insert 2 string variables into a table:

```
ALTER Procedure 
[dbo].[IND] (@VAssetID varchar(50), @UAssetID nvarchar(255))
As
BEGIN
  Declare @Query1  as varchar(max)
  Set @Query1 = 
  'Insert into IndMatch(V_AssetID,U_AssetID) values('+ @VAssetID +','+@UAssetID+')'
  EXECUTE(@Query1)
END
```

When I run the procedure with number strings only it works fine as soon as I try and insert alphanumeric codes the procedure fails.

When the procedure executes with numbers strings only:

```
Exec IND @VAssetID = '231243332', @UAssetID = '21343321'
```

The procedure executes fine with and inserts the values into the table.

When the procedure executes with alphanumeric strings:

```
Exec IND @VAssetID = '2312I43332', @UAssetID = '21T343R321'
```

It generates the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'I43332'.

Please assist

Comment: What data types are `V_AssetID` and `U_AssetID`?

Comment: Look at line 2 in the first code block, the data types in these 2 attributes are same

Comment: I realize what you're sending in -- I was asking about your actual table... See the answer below.  Or don't use dynamic sql -- just use: `Insert into IndMatch(V_AssetID,U_AssetID) values(@VAssetID, @UAssetID)`

Comment: Apologies I was being vague, Data types for the attributes `V_AssetID'`and  `U_AssetID` is the same as data types for `@VAssetID` and `@UAssetID`. `V_AssetID varchar(50), U_AssetID nvarchar(255)`. Thanks for the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the [ ' ] around the values.

It will try to execute an insert like so:

```
Insert into IndMatch(V_AssetID,U_AssetID) values(2312I43332,21T343R321 )
```

but the correct syntax should be

```
Insert into IndMatch(V_AssetID,U_AssetID) values('2312I43332','21T343R321' )
```

you need to do this:

```
ALTER Procedure 
[dbo].[IND] (@VAssetID varchar(50), @UAssetID nvarchar(255))
As
BEGIN
  Declare @Query1  as varchar(max)
  Set @Query1 = 
  'Insert into IndMatch(V_AssetID,U_AssetID) values('''+ @VAssetID +''','''+@UAssetID+''')'
  EXECUTE(@Query1)
END
```

Run this and this should explain it:

```
DECLARE @Query1 VARCHAR(MAX), @VAssetID VARCHAR(50), @UAssetID NVARCHAR(255);

SET @VAssetID = '231243332';

SET @UAssetID = '21343321';

SET @Query1 = 'Insert into IndMatch(V_AssetID,U_AssetID) values('+@VAssetID+','+@UAssetID+')';

PRINT @Query1;

SET @Query1 = 'Insert into IndMatch(V_AssetID,U_AssetID) values('''+@VAssetID+''','''+@UAssetID+''')';

PRINT @Query1;
```

PRINT RESULT:

[image]

Better yet you can do this as I don't see a need for dynamic sql here:

```
ALTER Procedure 
[dbo].[IND] (@VAssetID varchar(50), @UAssetID nvarchar(255))
As
BEGIN


   Insert into IndMatch(V_AssetID,U_AssetID) values(  @VAssetID  , @UAssetID ) 

END
```

Comment: Thanks for that, May I request an explanation please?

Answer (score 3):

Why execute as a string? This'll work just fine:

```
      ALTER Procedure [dbo].[IND] (@VAssetID varchar(50), @UAssetID nvarchar(255))
      As
      BEGIN
      Insert into IndMatch(V_AssetID,U_AssetID) values(@VAssetID, @UAssetID)
      END
```